# Dynamic query with Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to build a Spring Boot application for REST APIs.

I have to dynamically create queries based on the `PathVariable` in the endpoints.

Example:
`/{productName}/details` - based on the `{productName}`, my select queries and inner joins will change.

How do I provide this endpoint-query mapping? I did a bit of reading on this and the most suggested method was using JPA Criteria query, but I am not sure if it suits my requirement.

Should I go ahead and try implementing with JPA Criteria or write different queries in xml files?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: had a look at spring-data-jpa ?

Comment: Well no, I am kind of lost, so looking for suggestions! Thanks, I will definitely look into it.